# jQuery Mobile Listview Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I create a simple page using JQM. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li>Acura</li>
            <li>Audi</li>
            <li>BMW</li>
            <li>Cadillac</li>
            <li>Ferrari</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

When I preview it, the listview looks different from what inside the JQM docs website.

[image]

Am I doing any mistakes?

Comment: Your editor adds `&nbsp;` between elements.

Comment: @Omar, so how to fix that?

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ruva5c2q/